# Entity linking vs aliasing

Tags: nlp, entity-linking

The process of finding entity in a knowledge base (KB) that a given keyphrase in a text refers to is called entity linking. I have the
opposite problem. I have an entity in my knowledge base (KB) and I want to find all the ways people might refer to this entity. For instance, I have "Madonna" (singer) and I am looking for aliases like "Louise Ciccone", "Madonna Ritchie", "Queen of Pop", "Mo", etc.

Is it called aliasing? Or there is a better name in the literature?

I guess finding the right key words will help me find related research.

Comment: As far as I know this is also part of entity linking, since the task would also require a corpus of documents containing candidate persons names which may or may not represent the same entity. By applying entity linking one obtains the link between the occurrences and the entity, then it's easy to collect the distinct occurrences for the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to call them synonyms, a word or phrase that means exactly or nearly the same as another word or phrase.

Entity linking is mapping words of interest to corresponding unique entities in a knowledge base. It is useful to think of the unique entities in knowledge base as hashes and all surface forms as synonyms.